# How do I test if R is running as Rscript?

Tags: r, hadoop, rscript

I have code in a single R file that I want to be able to source (i.e., to define my functions etc.) within RStudio during development, and also run using the `#! /usr/bin/env Rscript` syntax via the command line (actually, using Hadoop). For the latter, I need the last thing that `Rscript` does to be to kick off the analysis (i.e., using a call to a `main()` function). For the former, I don't want my `main()` function called. I'd like to be able to test if the code is running within Rscript (or, alternatively, within RStudio), so that I can either execute `main()` or not. Is this possible, please?

One solution would be to break my code into multiple files, but I'd rather avoid this if possible (to make the Hadoop stuff slightly easier).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning RStudio - I wasn't aware of this software program until now, but I'm glad I 'found' it.

Comment: No worries, Jura25. It's much less mature than the Matlab or Mathematica front ends, but does the job very well for R.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `interactive` to test if R is running in interactive mode.  `interactive` will return `FALSE` under Rscript and `TRUE` under (most?) GUIs.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I can't believe I didn't find this…

Comment: After 9+ years I still find this useful. BTW `interactive()` returns a TRUE even when used inside a file that is sourced, in Rstudio. Is that expected?

Comment: @LazarusThurston: yes, that's expected. RStudio is an interactive console, so it's `TRUE` even if you `source()` a file.